# How to add a callable function to a Sympy expression

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, sympy

If I have an expression `x = Symbol('x')` and `f1=x**2` and I want to further add some `f2` where `f2 = interp1d(t, y)` is scipy interpolation. How does one turn `f2` into an expression such that I have somthing like `f = x**2 + f2(x)` so that I can later evaluate `f` as `f.subs(x, some_number)`?

Due to specification of the code, I can't evaluate `f1` and `f2` separatelly and then add the resulting numbers, I need to be able to add it to an existing sympy expression and evaluate it using something like `.subs()`

Comment: What prevents you from evaluting them differently?

Comment: Rather than `subs` would it work to use `lambdify` at the point that you want to call `interp1d`?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin the problem is that these sympy expressions are generated dynamically if I were to turn those sympy expressions dynamically into callables through ```lambdify``` then somehow combine them into one callable which seems quite complicated as I'm dealing with multiple variables.

Comment: The idea would be to call `lambdify` only once at the end of the process.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I wonder how that would work as a lot of the equations include dividing by a variable. So I have sympy terms together with callable functions in the numerator and a sympy variable expression in the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way but it requires hard-coding the function to be called in the class:

```
f2 = lambda t: np.sin(t)

class MyFunc(Function):
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, arg):
        arg = sympify(arg, strict=True)
        if arg.is_Number:
            return sympify(f2(float(arg)), strict=True)
```

More like Davide's answer but with a couple of fixes:

```
class FuncWrapper(Symbol):
    """Wraps a python callable as a Basic instance"""
    def __new__(cls, func, name):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, name)
        obj._wrapped = func
        return obj

    @property
    def wrapped(self):
        return self._wrapped

    def _hashable_content(self):
        return (self.wrapped,) # needed for __eq__

    def eval(self, arg):
        if arg.is_Number:
            return sympify(self.wrapped(float(arg)))

    def __call__(self, arg):
        return Call(self, arg)


class Call(Function):
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, func, arg):
        arg = sympify(arg)

        result = func.eval(arg)
        if result is not None:
            return result
```

With that you have:

```
In [61]: f = FuncWrapper(np.sin, 'f')

In [62]: x + f(x)
Out[62]: x + Call(f, x)

In [63]: _.subs(x, 1)
Out[63]: 1.84147098480790
```

Answer (score 0):

One very risky way would be to create a wrapper object for your numerical function, like this:

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
var("x")

# symbolic expression
f1 = cos(x)
# numerical function
f2 = lambda t: np.sin(t)

class MyFunc(Expr):
    """Create a symbolic wrapper to a numerical function."""
    
    def __new__(cls, arg, **kwargs):
        obj = Expr.__new__(cls, **kwargs)
        obj._custom_func = arg
        return obj
    
    def _subs(self, old, new, **hints):
        return self._custom_func(float(new))

expr = f1 + MyFunc(f2)
expr.subs(x, np.pi/4)
# out: 1.41421356237309
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Though why would this be considered risky?

Comment: It's risky because it returns non-Basic instances in `_subs` where the code calling that method would expect Basic. Also all instances of this class would be considered equivalent by `__eq__` which would mess up under caching.